# MiKTeX 2.9 Portable update corruption

Tags: miktex

Since yesterday's (22.6.2015) update my MiKTeX 2.9 on a USB stick no longer works. Trying to start it on a Windows 7 desktop returns the error

> Windows API error 2: could not find file

The only thing I can think of is a clean install, which I would rather not do.

Comment: I can confirm this error. It happened to me to. It seems that mixtex delete some important files, and does not copy in new one. When I run the update, I fist got the error that mixtex could not find the package manager due to missing msvcp120.dll-file. When I closed the icontray-app and restart, the cmd-file did not find the icon-tray.exe. I checked, and the files did not exist on my system.

Comment: I can confirm this error also on Win8.1

Comment: @Sveinung: I had (in a normal, single-user, non-portable miktex) also an error regarding a missing dll and couldn't start the package manager. But the command line version worked fine and after `mpm --install=miktex-vc120-bin` everything was ok (perhaps you need a `mpm --update-db` first).

Comment: So, is there any chance, that this issue gets resolved in one of the next update cycles?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just get an error mpm.exe is not recognised as a command. In the portable version, lot of .exe-files were removed during the update (also the icon-tray program).

Comment: Is mpm.exe not there or only not in the path?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It's not there. I have miktex/bin in my path. I run the portable version from the c:drive due to limited rights on my work computer.

Answer (score 7):

It helped me:

1. Run mo.exe
2. From "packages" tab select miktex 2.9 executables -> mpm cli, miktex-vc120-bin,  miktex-internal-bin
3. Update again.

(miktex portable with /bin added to path)

Comment: Well, I got the error that the program could not be run because mvscp120.dll was missing. The problem seems to be that I run the update from the GUI. I will try to reinstall the portable version and update the .dll from the command line.

Comment: @Sveinung: Get msvcp120.dll free from Microsoft. It is part of Visual C++ 2013 redistributable. Install it, then do what Stefan Kottwitz wrote above. Worked for me. If it works for you too, then be sure to mark SK's post as the solution.

Comment: @RobtA It is much better to use Ulrike Fischer's receipt: `mpm --install=miktex-vc120-bin`.

Comment: @Sveinung: Ah, yes. I forgot that Miktex will automatically make other changes, as needed. It will even do this midway through processing a document! I use TeX on both Linux as Texlive, and Windows as Miktex.

Comment: Different ones were missing for me, but this worked.

Comment: @RobtA I get "log4cxx: No appender could be found for logger (mpmcli)."