# After fixing MiKTeX 2.9 Portable update corruption the command window won't appear

Tags: miktex

Today I installed MikTeX 2.9 portable. After closing it once I couldn't open the taskbar icon again. An error window appeared stating:

> Windows API error 2: could not find file

I followed the procedure by @Aliexx and @StefanKottwitz from here:
[MiKTeX 2.9 Portable update corruption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251647/miktex-2-9-portable-update-corruption)

1. Run mo.exe
2. From "packages" tab select miktex 2.9 executables -> mpm cli, miktex- vc120-bin, miktex-internal-bin
3. update packages

Now I can access the taskbar icon again, but clicking "Command Promp" does not provide me with the usual command window. It only pops up briefly and the vanishes.

Is anyone familiar with this or has an idea? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to reboot the computer first?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by the old "have you tried turning it off and on again" trick (see comment above).